# PhpStorm Referenced method is not found in subject class

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm

I am new to PHP OOP and trying to learn it. I know that this question is asked many times and i made a lot of search but i can't managed to fix of this warning.

I am using only one class file for query and and assigning. Theese four methods **query(), fetch_assoc(), free()** and **escape_string()** are giving warning. I tired to use PHPDoc comments but warning is still here. What i am doing wrong?

**1. method:**

```
$result = self::$database->query($sql);
```

**2. method:**

```
while ($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

**3. method:**

```
$result->free();
```

**4. method:**

```
$sql .= "WHERE id='" . self::$database->escape_string($id) . "'";
```

This sample code is modified from Linkedin(Lynda) training video.

Class file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class User
 */
class User {

    // ------ START OF ACTIVE RECORD CODE ------
    /**
     * @var $database
     */
    static protected $database;

    /**
     * @param $database
     */
    public static function set_database($database): void {
        self::$database = $database;
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @return array
     */
    public static function find_by_sql($sql):array {
        $result = self::$database->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            exit("Database query failed.");
        }

        // result into objects
        $object_array = [];

        while ($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $object_array[] = self::instantiate($record);
        }

        $result->free();

        return $object_array;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function find_all():array {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        return self::find_by_sql($sql);
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function find_by_id($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
        $sql .= "WHERE id='" . self::$database->escape_string($id) . "'";
        $obj_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
        if (!empty($obj_array)) {
            return array_shift($obj_array);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $record
     * @return User
     */
    protected static function instantiate($record):User {
        // new self() creates a new User class
        $object = new self();
        // auto assign values from database to class properties
        foreach ($record as $property => $value) {
            if (property_exists($object, $property)) {
                $object->$property = $value;
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }
    // ------ END OF ACTIVE RECORD CODE ------

    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $name;
    public $gender;
    public $member_date;
    public $last_login_date;
    public $last_login_ip;
    public $birthdate;
    public $profile_pic;
    public $facebook;
    public $twitter;
}
?>
```

initialization file for setting database:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
require_once "db_functions.php";

// TODO: change with spl_autoload
require_once "classes/User.php";

$database = db_connect();
User::set_database($database);
?>
```

functions file:

```
<?php
/*
 * DB Functions File
 */

function db_connect() {
    $connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $connection->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
    check_db_connection($connection);
    return $connection;
}

function check_db_connection($connection) {
    if ($connection->connect_errno) {
        $message = "Database connection failed!";
        $message .= "<br />";
        $message .= $connection->connect_errno;
        $message .= ": ";
        $message .= $connection->connect_error;
        exit($message);
    }
}

function db_disconnect($connection) {
    if ($connection !== null) {
        $connection->close();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: *"I tired to use PHPDoc comments but warning is still here. What i am doing wrong?"* Your PHPDocs are incomplete -- they are missing the most important part (the main purpose of using them) -- the typehint (what type that variable/parameter is). Check https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md or https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/index.html

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne
I declared missing types for paramaters/variables and some of them fixed.
But **$result->free();** is still same. I am not able to declare it as a **@var**

Comment: Use inline `@var` and typehint `$result` -- e.g. place it just before `$result` assignment: `/** @var MyType $result */` and use correct type.

Comment: Thanks.
I've placed it as mysqli_result just before assigning and it is fixed.
But why i must place it in the method, not before defining method?

Comment: Without seeing what you have got now -- no ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have got as a solution.

```
/**
 * @param string $sql
 * @return array $object_array
 */
public static function find_by_sql($sql):array {
    /** @var mysqli_result $result */
    $result = self::$database->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        exit("Database query failed.");
    }
    // result into objects
    $object_array = [];
    while ($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($record);
    }
    $result->free();
    return $object_array;
}
```